# MYSQL - join 2 tables, match multiple columns - update value from other table where multiple values match

Tags: mysql

I need to join two tables (TableCorrected) with (TableOriginal). Both tables have columns for ID-number and Articlenumber. Both tables also have a column named "Quantity".

I want to join the two tables, match ID-number AND Articlenumber and update the Quantity-value from "TableOriginal" to "TableCorrected" ONLY where ID-number as well as Articlenumber matches.

I've started a statement as below - but I'm sure it's not correct, returns 0 result.

```
UPDATE TableOriginal
INNER JOIN TableCorrected ON TableOriginal.ID = TableCorrected.ID
SET TableOriginal.Quantity = TableCorrected.Quantity
WHERE TableCorrected.ID = TableOriginal.ID 
  AND TableCorrected.Article = TableOriginal.Article
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I'm sure it's not correct

It is correct. But not optimal. More clear is, for example,

```sql
UPDATE TableOriginal
INNER JOIN TableCorrected USING (ID, Article)
SET TableOriginal.Quantity = TableCorrected.Quantity;
```

or

```sql
UPDATE TableOriginal
INNER JOIN TableCorrected ON TableOriginal.ID      = TableCorrected.ID
                         AND TableOriginal.Article = TableCorrected.Article
SET TableOriginal.Quantity = TableCorrected.Quantity;
```

---

> returns 0 result.

UPDATE does not return rows. Rather than SELECT.

Comment: Thanks! Checked the data now instead of the Output - values corrected as intended :). Appreciate your input!

Comment: @Grovlimpa222 *Checked the data now instead of the Output* Not "instead". Check "in addition" - what if the query execution produces some error?